# Nginx: Least connections with sticky sessions

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy and need sticky sessions, so I'm using ip_hash as the balancing algorithm.

I'd prefer to do use least_conn (least connections) as the balancing algorithm. Is it possible to do least connections with sticky sessions?

Comment: any news ? did you solve your problem with Nginx ? thanks

Comment: I just left it as is in my case. I believe nginx pro did support what I was after but you have to pay to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pure load-balancing point of view, it doesn't make any sense to enable persistence and least conn, since persistence is an exeption to load-balancing: once persistence is enabled, then the load-balancer won't use the load balancing algorithm anymore, since it knows where to route the request.
When persistence is enabled, then the load-balancing algorithm is only used to route the first request of each user.
On Web traffic, the number of connections per server change a LOT every miliseconds... Hence that's why balancing users based on such metric doesn't make much sense when persistence is required.

More information here about persistence and load-balancing:
http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/

By the way, unfortunately, you've just relized the difference between a software which can do load-balancing (nginx) and with a real load-balancer...

Simply switch to HAProxy for this purpose:

```
backend bk_myapp
 cookie MyAPP insert indirect nocache
 balance leastconn
 server srv1 10.0.0.1:80 check cookie srv1
 server srv2 10.0.0.2:80 check cookie srv2
```

Baptiste

Comment: I'm confused. First you say it doesn't make sense and then you say a real load balancer does do that stuff. I marked your answer as correct anyway.

Comment: Well, that's not because leastconn + persistence doesn't make sense in your particular case (web traffic) that's it's not useful in some other cases (IE protocols with long time sessions such as IMAP).

That's why Ithought it was useful as well to mention that a "real" load-balancer can do this out of the box.